# Bootstrap Menu Disappears After Clicking Menu Item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When the browser window is reduced to mobile size, Bootstrap menu disappears after clicking a menu item and reappears only after the browser window is expanded or reduced.

[link to live site](http://www.americangraduate.org/)

When inspecting the elements in Chrome browser, I noticed that the following html disappears when the menu is invisible and appears when the menu is visible.

```
<div class="fake-bg" style="height: 928px;"></div>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav clearfix btn-gpup" style="">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

I'm also thinking that there may be some conflicts between templates and/or plugins but there are so many plugins that I don't know the easiest way to go about troubleshooting that.

If anyone can figure this out or give me direction, thank you!

Comment: The `nav-collapse` element is being removed completely when you click on a menu item, probably something in your javascript.

Comment: Also you're loading a ton of Javascript, including 2 different versions of jQuery, probably want to clean that up.

Answer (score 0):

in http://bento.cdn.pbs.org/hostedbento-prod/filer_public/_bento_media/passport/js/menu.js there is a function called fitNavigation() (row 66). It seems that it takes care of adding that mobile menu. It is called on document ready but only for non mobile devices - check rows 318 - 326. It's also called on resize (row 349). This is the reason why when you resize to see it. If you refresh the browser in mobile mode you will never see that menu initial, you will see it only after a little resize or if you load the page in desktop mode and then resize to mobile. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see what you are referring to but how do I fix it? Call fitNavigation() if mobile and is not mobile?

Comment: In my opinion you should call it for mobile. But without knowing the general idea of that js I can not tell on 100%. You should know better how it is supposed to work. Try to just take it out of that check on document ready(row318) and call it after it.

Comment: The other option is to have the markup inside the template, instead of appending it from the javascript.